# libgcc and libstdcplusplus rpms version supported by node 14 LTC (v14.15.4)

Tags: node.js, gcc, libstdc++, libgcc

I have a query regarding which gcc versions are supported by node js 14 LTC as in my project we recently upgraded to node js 14 LTC and the libgcc and libstdcplusplus rpms version that were used earlier for AIX 6.1 and AIX 7.1 was 4.9.2-1 but now we are looking to upgrade the libgcc and libstdcplusplus versions as well.

Please let me know what versions of libgcc and libstdcplusplus are supported by node js version - v14.15.4

Comment: Those are parts of `gcc`, not standalone packages. If in doubt, ask your Node.js-supplier about the used gcc-version. (Or _compiler version,_ to be more precise: if it is `xlc` then the gcc-components are irrelevant.)

Answer (score 0):

I am using node v14.17.1 and on AIX 7.1 works with below versions
libgcc-8.3.0-2
libstdc++-8.3.0-2